# StringWriter/StringIO for Perl

Tags: perl, io, stringio

I'm trying to write some unit tests for some communications code that writes to a socket.  During testing I'd like to have my communications library write to a string, then I can compare the contents of the string to what I expect to be written.

In Java I'd use something like a `StringWriter` so that my communications code could write to the standard `Writer` interface and at the end I can just ask for all of the data that was written.

Is there an equivalent of this or Python's StringIO for Perl?  Is something like this already built in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Since v5.8 you can open an output handle directly to a scalar reference.

```
my $output;
open my $handle, '>', \$output;
print $handle "foo\n";
printf $handle "%d\n", 123;
close $handle;
print $output;   # => "foo\n123\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do similar things with [IO::Stringy](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/IO-stringy-2.110/).